# Why didn't the experimentation for the 13-day rule push through?

Tags: death-note

Ep25 spoiler

> In the episode where L dies, he mentions wanting to test the 13-day rule. If the 13-day rule is disproven, Light and Misa become suspects again. L dies and then

apparently everyone seems to have forgotten about the test. What happened? I seem to recall most of the task force disagreed with L and then

> when he died, the majority opinion prevailed.

Comment: It would be prudent to note that the original Kira along with the 2nd Kira would have died, should the rule have been true.

Comment: @ʇosɥıuonʞʎonʞo Why is that prudent to note?

Comment: because of the lapse of killings for 14 days during Light's confinement

Comment: @ʇosɥıuonʞʎonʞo And then...? What? L thought the rule is fake. L wanted to test it, but then he died. Why didn't the remaining task force members test it?

Comment: basically the rule that saved Light and Misa from confinement is one that could easily be proven false, because there was no reason for Kira to suddenly allow himself to die

Comment: @ʇosɥıuonʞʎonʞo What? I don't understand at what you're driving. Are you trying to answer my question? Are you helping me improve my question?

Comment: I'm pointing out that this too was missed by the entirety of the cast, possibly leading the plot in another direction had it been discovered. But alas, it was never brought up again...

Comment: @ʇosɥıuonʞʎonʞo Ah so you mean you are inclined to agree that this might be a plothole?

Comment: Yes, I thought this would have been exploited later on in the series to reveal him as Kira, but that never happened.

Comment: @ʇosɥıuonʞʎonʞo Now all your comments make sense. Thanks. I recommend you state the context of what you're saying or something like that

Comment: @кяαzєя You can post that as an answer if you want unless you actually agree with Memor-X.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For them to test the 13-day rule the Death Note has to be used. the Task Force's disagreeing with L was over the fact they would have to sacrifice someone for an experiment.

The Japanese Police were already a bit iffy of L since the Lind L. Tailor incident where L had a condemned criminal sacrificed just to test how Kira kills and where they may be, and the Police and the Task Force have to keep the moral high ground and not go around killing people for tests/experiments, especially with the Death Note.

Also remember that the Task Force didn't learn about the Death Note or the fake rules until quite some time after Light's and Misa's confinement where "Kira" was a member of the Yotsuba Group, all the while Light was handcuffed to L. to the Task Force this was more than enough to clear Light's and Misa's names without stooping down to Kira's Level, L on the other hand can see himself on the same level as Light as per what he said in Death Note Relight 2: L's Successors

> There are...many types of monsters in this world: Monsters who will not show themselves and who cause trouble; monsters who abduct children; monsters who devour dreams; monsters who suck blood, and... monsters who always tell lies. Lying monsters are a real nuisance. They are much more cunning than other monsters. They pose as humans even though they have no understanding of the human heart. They eat even though they've never experienced hunger. They study even though they have no interest in academics. They seek friendship even though they do not know how to love. **If I were to encounter such a monster, I would likely be eaten by it. Because in truth, I am that monster.**

Source: [L - Quotes (9th point)](http://deathnote.wikia.com/wiki/L_(character)#Quotes)

take notice of the lines i emphasized. it forebodes his death but also describes the kind of person Light/Kira is, and that L himself is just like that so L would have no problem "testing" the Death Note

Comment: Right disagreement. Thanks. Wow so if just one person agreed with L, Light and Misa would have been thrown back into suspicion? Hey actually so why didn't Mello test it and then report back the result if disproven?

Comment: @BCLC maybe but i would assume they would have to show they same to the same conclusions as L and not just agreeing with him. as for Mello i'm quite sure that aprt from him not being on the right side when Sidoh came down to reclaim his Death Note it was only L that suspected it was fake rule. i haven't seen the series in a while so i can't remember when Mello or Near found out about the fake rules

Comment: Mello found about the fake rule from Sidoh. He told Near about it in exchange for the picture of Mello

Comment: @BCLC still Mello was on the wrong side and the Task Force wasn't exactly trusting of Near. for the Task Force to believe Near Sidoh would have to call Ryuk out as if i remember right Ryuk wasn't exactly confirming or denying if the rules were fake or not